# Send all traffic to network interface and receive from other

Tags: linux, networking, routes, intercept, bridge

i'm triying to imagine how to do:
(with Linux Debian based distro)

I have PC with 4 NIC:

```
eth0 = Internet Access (connect to router WAN)
eth1 = Local lan
eth2 = OUT NIC
eth3 = IN NIC
```

I need to send all traffic from eth1 (local lan) to eth2, receive the same traffic from eth3 and route to eth0.

The idea is send all eth1 traffic to external device over eth2, the external device inspect the packets and send to PC again on eth3, then my PC Linux route traffic to eth0

Is posible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You're running linux on a PC? We need to know the version first off. Second you are looking into IProutes if you want to redirect traffic from one NIC to another.

Comment: Sorry, I forget mention that i have Linux Debian based disto. I need send all traffic to eth2 before routing process, then receive the same traffic over eth3 and then ... route to final destination. I'm nedd to send all trafic to other external device and then receive from the external device and act as router.

Comment: Try this website it should give you what you are looking for. [IP Forwarding](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I know NAT, I try to do whithout modify packets.

Comment: `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth3 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: This will just create an iptables rule for *allowing* forwarding. It doesn't create routing rules to actual forward this traffic.

Comment: Yes, I return to the project and the rules from JeremyA1 only permit forward traffic not send ALL traffic from eth0 to eth2 whitout modification (NATing)